# Chowla's Construction of prime having least quadratic non-residue $\gg \log p$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

[This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969420?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) paper by NC Ankeny mentions that " S. Chowla has proved that there exist infinitely many primes $k$ where the
 first $c_1\log k$ residues $(\bmod k)$ are all quadratic residues".

I recently found a proof of this [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/LeastQuadraticNonResidue.pdf).

The proof constructs such primes using this idea:

1. Consider numbers which satisfies these condition : $n=1\bmod 8$ and $n=1\bmod r_i$ where $r_i$ are first consecutive odd primes less than $y$.
2. Let $R:= 8\prod r_i $ , clearly $n=1\bmod R$ by Chinese remainder theorem.
3. By Linniks there exist a prime $p$ in this arithmetic progression $\{ 1+rk_j\}$ such that $p= \mathcal{O}(R^6)$.
4. Note that for this prime all numbers less than $y$ are quadratic residue, since p $\equiv  1 \bmod 8 \implies \big(\frac{a}{p} \big) = \big( \frac{p}{a} \big) $.
5. By prime number theorem it is easy to see that y = $O(\log p)$

But this analysis clearly doest rule out the possibility of having least quadratic non-residue $O(\log p)$ . Infact if we write all the constants and work it out than it doesn't even rule out the possibility of least quadratic non residue less than $10\log p$.

I want to know is this just what Chowla proved or there is a better argument for this. Any refrence for the same would be of great help.

Comment: Graham and Ringrose proved that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that the least quadratic nonresidue $n_p$ satisfies $n_p \gg \log p \log\log\log p$. The paper can be found [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-3464-7_18).

Comment: @i707107 your comment gives the answer to my question. kindly write it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am writing as an answer, I will put more information than the comment.

[Graham and Ringrose](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-3464-7_18) proved that:

> There are infinitely many primes $p$ such that 
>   $$
> n_p\gg \log p \log\log\log p.$$

[Montgomery](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540056416) proved that:

> If the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis(GRH) is true, then there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that 
>   $$n_p\gg \log p \log\log p.$$